# passing a double pointer into a function and assigning it an address of a pointer local to a function

Tags: c, pointers

Below is some code that passes a double pointer into a function. the double pointer is then assigned the address of a pointer created **in the function**. When I print out the address stored in the double pointer it prints NULL, which is the value I initially gave the double pointer before passing it into the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
};

void append( struct node **nodePtr );

int main()
{
    struct node **nodePtr = NULL;

    append( nodePtr );
    printf("\nnodePtr = %p", nodePtr);

    return 0;
}

void append( struct node **nodePtr )
{
    // creating new node
    struct node *currentNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // assigning the address of currentNode to the double pointer NodePtr
    nodePtr = &currentNode;

    printf("\n&currentNode = %p", &currentNode);
}
```

[This is the result I get when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II1qI.png)

I know that if you pass a pointer into a function it is passed by reference, which means any changes you make to the pointer in the function will not disappear when you access the pointer outside the function.

My question is, why can't I access the address of currentNode outside the function. I assigned it to a double pointer so I should be able to access it out side the function? right?

**Above has been answered already**

Thanks for your answer paul, it worked perfectly. I tried to expand onto the code. I wanted to assign nodePtr to the struct pointer called *head*. When I called the function I wanted to store the address in currentNode into the head pointer.

Initially I thought changing the code inside the function displayed below would work.

```
*nodePtr = currentNode;
```

but this didn't work because I was just changing the contents in nodePtr not the contents in head.

I then tried to initializing nodePtr to the address of head.

```
struct node *nodePtr = &head;
```

but this didn't work because it is not a double pointer. If I initialize it as a double pointer I just run into the same problem I did before.

below is all my code so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
};

void append( struct node **nodePtr );

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *nodePtr = head;

    append( &nodePtr );

    printf("%p", head);
    return 0;
}

void append( struct node **nodePtr )
{
    // creating new node
    struct node *currentNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // assigning the address of currentNode to the double pointer NodePtr
    *nodePtr = currentNode;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "double pointer". There are only pointers. Pointers can point to anything, including pointers. Pointers pointing to pointers are still just pointers, not "double pointers". If you keep this in mind, lots of confusion should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main should be:

```
int main()
{
    struct node *nodePtr = NULL;

    append( &nodePtr );
    printf("\nnodePtr = %p", nodePtr);

    return 0;
}
```

So you pass the *address* of the nodePtr from main.

In append, you must now dereference that pointer:

```
    // assigning the newly allocated currentNode to the double pointer NodePtr
    *nodePtr = currentNode;
```

(So don't asssign the address of the local variable `currentNode` because that local variable will cease to exist after the function returns. You assign the pointer returned by `malloc`.)

I suggest you use pen and paper to draw the memory of `main` and `append` and draw the pointers to see what is happening and what gets stored where.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a triple pointer in the function, if you insist on using a double pointer.

In your code, the changes are performed inside the function, but they just don't persist after its termination.

However, you don't really need to use a double pointer in your `main()`, just use a single pointer, and leave the function as is.